# Developing for Kinect on the Xbox

Tags: kinect, xbox

I am working on building a prototype for an game that will eventually be commercial but is not at present. Since I am not a licensed Xbox developer, I don't have access to the official Microsoft XDK. I am aware of the Kinect for Windows SDK that was recently released, as well as open source alternatives like OpenKinect. Unfortunately both of those options are Windows only. I've heard that Microsoft eventually plans to release Kinect support for XNA, but who knows when that will happen. My question: In the short term, is there any library, clever hack, or open source alternative that I can use to get my prototype working on the Xbox itself?

Answer (score 3):

No. The only way to do native development for the Xbox 360 is to become a registered developer. Your best option for building a prototype is to develop on the PC using the Windows Kinect SDK if applying for registered developer status is not an option for you. If you develop with DirectX 9 and stick to core Win32 APIs you shouldn't have too much trouble porting your code to the Xbox 360 later. The biggest thing to be aware of for porting is endianness issues.